# Buscamos ideas para webcasts

Tags: discusión, webcast

Nos gustaría abrir las puertas para invitar a nuestros miembros a que sugieran o se apunten para participar como panelistas en los webcasts de este año.  Sabemos que existe mucho talento por acá y estamos interesados en poder explorar esta parte de nuestra comunidad.

Así que, ahí les dejo la invitación.  Si tienen un tema interesante o quieren participar, apúntense al dejar una respuesta en esta pregunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un tema bastante interesante sería Cloud Services, específicamente me refiero a una batalla que ya dio inicio entre Azure y AWS, los cuales ya se están dando con todo :D

Comment: Xamarin (Forms y Clásico), ASP.net Core, Docker y micro-servicios, TypeScript, Vue :D

Comment: Cuenten conmigo :D

Comment: el de VUE me gusta.. algun alma caritativa que se anime? ponelo en una respuesta @fredyfx!

Comment: GraphQl? Creo que seria interesante.

Answer (score 10):

Me gustaría escuchar historias de guerra... gente trabajando en proyectos interesantes (que ell@s consideren interesantes).

En este webcast, no tendríamos un tema específico, sino gente compartiendo desafíos, soluciones, problemas (de todo tipo) y anécdotas.

Si hubiera interesad@s en formar parte de este panel, podríamos hacer una suerte de "call for papers" donde se postulen y entre todos votemos cuáles queremos escuchar.

En fin, puede ser una pésima idea... pero en lo personal aprendo mucho de las historias de otr@s. Y los aprendizajes no técnicos son los que más se me dificultan ;)

Comment: a mi me gusta.. pero mas que un webcast es un asado, y termina de madrugada!!! jajajaja +1

Comment: @gbianchi es cierto... puede ser difícil de moderar...

Comment: pero puede ser muy divertido.. es mas.. podes hacer toda una serie :p.. seguro va a ser mas interesante que esos de las APIs...

Comment: features raras con bastantes restricciones cambiantes de acuerdo a lo que vayan seleccionando, que sea dinámico para agregar múltiples, editar, eliminar y que se vea bonito, en 1 día. Esto ni con cafeína intravenosa sale en ese tiempo.

Answer (score 7):

Algunas ideas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Experiencias sobre cómo realizar estimados con la mayor presición posible.
- Desarrollo web: ASP.net Core, TypeScript, Vue.
- Desarrollo móvil: Xamarin (Xamarin Forms y Xamarin Classic).
- Arquitectura: Docker, micro-servicios y serverless.
- Base de datos: Técnicas de análisis de queries y tunning para un buen performance. (Disculpen la mezcla con el inglés, siento que suena más llamativo)
- Un tema algo picante: ¿Cómo hacerle entender al Project Manager(PM) que 9 mujeres no generan un bebé en 1 mes? Dicho de otra manera, compartir experiencias sobre cómo hablar con un jefe no-informático o gente no-informática que tiene poder en el proyecto donde estás y piden cambios en un tiempo surrealista y sin asignación de recursos adicionales donde lo único que puede hacer posible dichos cambios es conseguir un DeLorean y/o programar en la habitación del tiempo de Kamisama. A veces los PM venden proyectos pensando que los desarrolladores tenemos la habilidad de programar deteniendo el espacio-tiempo.

Comment: El ultimo tema es lo mejor leído en mucho tiempo, usare dicha frase para cerrar rápido una discusión.

Comment: Hahaha no había visto este punto: "9 mujeres generan un bebé en 1 mes". Creo que si un "PM" tiene esta idea en realidad no es un "PM", ese tipo de ideas las he notado en personas que tienen un equipo a su cargo pero no fueron nunca desarrolladores, no conocen alguna metodología o no tienen conocimientos de IT :-/.

Comment: y tampoco tienen ideas de liderazgo, el título de PM está de adorno xD!!!

Answer (score 3):

un tema interesante y que quizás mucha gente pasa por alto, es el tema de llevar a cabo el desarrollo de proyectos, ya sea de grado, personal, empresarial, entre otros., pero enfocado en el tema de la redacción de este, sea el libro o articulo para una revista institucional, etc., ya que el desconocimiento de esto, muchas veces de este se ve reflejado en situaciones como:

- Deficiencia en la redacción del libro
- Proyectos no acordes con la rama que fue el fuerte durante el estudio de la carrera.
- Desconocimiento de metodologías.
- Reconocer que proyecto puede ser el mas conveniente.
- Visualizar la idea y que el tamaño elegido sea realizable.

Hay otros muchos temas que tocar aquí.

Comment: Este tema es interesante, el desarrollo de un proyecto no es solo codificarlo y listo, hay que medir con precisión las variantes y los distintos riesgos sin mencionar que para todo proyecto hay que medir la escalabilidad y tener en cuenta los diversos factores que amerita el proyecto. Me ha gustado, +1.

Comment: Y tenemos algun project manager en la sala? esto es una materia entera de la UNI!

Comment: @gbianchi sinceramente no lo se, pero seria bueno alguien que tenga experiencia en el tema, sea por experiencia o por que sea lo que tu dices.

Answer (score 3):

Un tema podría ser:

Administración de proyectos desde el punto de vista de administrador y desarrollador, conocer experiencia y recomendaciones en cuanto a gestión, herramientas, metodologías usadas, etc...

Podríamos aprovechar de los usuarios de la comunidad para que nos platiquen y nos den cátedra de su experiencia.

Answer (score 3):

Un tema interesante podría ser el trabajo en equipo, ya sea:

- metodologías de desarrollo de software, cuales han usado y creen que son eficientes
- integración continua
- roles en el equipo de trabajo
- control de versiones

entre otros temas que puedan surgir.